# Does this makefile make sense?

Tags: c++, makefile, include

i want to compile this small program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    cout << "SDL init failed"   << endl;
    return 1;
  }
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

which I can do successfully with:

```
g++ -o SDL_basic SDL_basic.cpp -I/opt/local/include/SDL2/ -l SDL2 -L/opt/local/lib/
```

I spent the last hour trying to modify the makefile I usually use to do the same:

```
CXX=g++
INC=-I/opt/local/include/SDL2/
LIBSEARCHPATH=-L/opt/local/lib/
LIBS=-l SDL2

OBJECTS=$(PROJECT).o
PROJECT=SDL_basic

$(PROJECT) : $(OBJECTS)
        ${CXX} $(CPFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ ${INC} ${LIBSEARCHPATH} ${LIBS}

.cpp.o :
        ${CXX} -c ${CPFLAGS} $? ${INC} ${LIBSEARCHPATH} ${LIBS}

clean :
        rm -f $(OBJECTS)
```

Running make finally works now, but if I run it a second time after a small change in the .cpp, I get the following warning:

```
clang: warning: -lSDL2: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/opt/local/lib/' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

Therefore my question. Does this make sense what I did in the makefile? Do the arguments ${INC} ${LIBSEARCHPATH} ${LIBS} really belong after both .cpp.o : and $(PROJECT) : $(OBJECTS) (Otherwise it does not seem to work)?

I hope somebody can help me.
Thank you a lot and best regards!!
F

Comment: You don't need `${LIBSEARCHPATH} ${LIBS}` for the compilation, they are needed only for the linking.

Comment: You should also use `$<` in your compile line, not `$?`.  And it's best to add an explicit `-o $@` to the compile line as well.  Really, if you just changed `INC` to `CPPFLAGS` (the default variable) then you can omit your own suffix rule entirely and just rely on make's built-in rule, which already knows how to build everything using best practices.